# Mininet OpenvSwitch error

Tags: mininet, openvswitch

I am trying to implement simple local net configuration with 3 hosts and 1 switch(with command: sudo mn —topo single,3). The idea is to implement that all the traffic will be duplicated to the host3 (port mirroring). I am trying to run command (in one line):

```
s1 ovs-vsctl -- set Bridge s1 mirrors=@m --\
 --id=@eth1 get Port s1-eth1 -- \
 --id=@eth2 get Port s1-eth2 -- \
 --id=@eth3 get Port s1-eth3 -- \
 --id=@m create Mirror name=mymirror \
 select-dst-port=@eth1,@eth2 select-src-port=@eth1,@eth2 output-port=@eth3
```

I get an error: `ovs-vsctl: no row «127.0.0.1» in table Bridge`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: BTW, thanks for posting this, this I feel is the neatest mirror cmd i have read. I was really stuck until you posted this.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, do you manage to run it?

Comment: yeah. Means i never got the error that you have posted. I have edited your question post. Run this on terminal probably. Though I don't understand your error.

Comment: Ok thanks.No, command is right as I have written it by myself on command line and have copied from there. Oh well, I guess it's another Mininet's mystery......anyway I found a way  to overpass this problem :) Good luck!

Comment: great. Do post your solution if you think it'll help someone else.